# Azure Dev Ops - Building an Xamarin Project fails

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#, azure-devops

I have created a Xamarin Forms solution that contains both an iOS and an Andoid project that uses F#.  I created a Azure Dev Ops pipeline (classic template, no YAML) and I am getting the following error when it attempts to build:

> error FS3053 : The type provider
>   'Xamarin.Android.FSharp.ResourceProvider' reported an error : The type
>   provider constructor has thrown an exception: [error CS0009: Metadata
>   file
>   `/Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/src/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   does not contain valid metadata]
>   [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/src/Droid/sameroom.mobile.droid.fsproj]

Can anyone add some insight from here?  It works fine building/running on my local macbook.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Instead of using the OOB Xamarin.iOS Build Solution task, use the MSBuild task and only point to the iOS project (iOS.fsproj)

[image]

Comment: Very appreciate your solution shared here. It would be much great if you can accept this answer:-)